# How to scope results with pivot table October Cms

Tags: laravel, relationship, octobercms

The solution to this is probably easy and I'm just missing it, but I can't seem to figure out how to limit "customers" based on the "user" that the customer belongs to.

This is a many to many relationship, so a customer can belong to more than one user and a user can have more than one customer.

Here is my relationship definition:

```
public $belongsToMany = [
    'user_id' => [
        'RainLab\User\Models\User',
        'table' => 'tablename_users_customers',
    ]
];
```

And here is the scope function that doesn't work as I'd expect:

```
public function scopeUser($query) {
    $user = Auth::getUser()->id;
    return $query->where('user_id', $user)->get();
}
```

Finally, here is my error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tblcustomers` where `user_id` = 1)
```

Obviously, the error is because the "user_id" column doesn't exist in the 'tblcustomers' table, but rather in the pivot table.  How can I use the "user_id" from the pivot table in my scope function?  I need to only display Customers that belong to the currently logged in user.

Comment: so what actually your scope is about, means you want customers with specific user attached to it right ?

Comment: @HardikSatasiya exactly! specifically the current user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this can be possible

But First thing is you need to remove `get()` method from the scope, `scope meant to return query` object for chaining methods further.

> Your relation and scope should look like this

```php
// relation
public $belongsToMany = [
    // PLEASE MAKE RELATION NAME CORRECT HERE
    'users' => [  // not user_id, use `users`
        'RainLab\User\Models\User',
        'table' => 'tablename_users_customers',
        // 'key' => 'customer_id', if needed
        // 'otherKey' => 'user_id' if needed
    ]
];


// scope
use RainLab\User\Models\User;
public function scopeUser($query) {    
    return $query->whereHas('users', function($usersQuery) {
        $user_id = Auth::getUser()->id;
        return $usersQuery->where((new User)->getTable() . '.id', $user_id);       
    });
}

// usage
$result = Customer::user()->get();
dd($result);  
// you will get only customers which has relation with current logged in user.
```

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: I had to move the $user_id - Auth::getUser()->id; inside the function($userQuery){...};.  Otherwise I was getting a $user_id undefined error.  After doing that, this works.  Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped you :+1